# PHP - Retrieve Data From mySQL Server

Tags: php, mysql

Does anyone know how to retrieve a piece of data and display the results in php file?
A similar query that I would enter is something like this:

```
SELECT 'email' FROM 'users' WHERE 'username' = 'bob'
```

Thus, the result would be just the email.

Thanks,

Kevin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To connect

```
$con = mysql_connect("host","userName","passWord");
if (!$con){die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());}
mysql_select_db("dbNameToSelect", $con);
```

To query

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT `email` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = 'bob'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
   // do stuff with $row['colName']
}
```

To close connection `mysql_close($con);`

Comment: How would i connect to a database?

Answer (score 1):

You need to connect and fetch data from a database, like mysql. Check the code below:

```
$server = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$database = "mysampledb";

mysql_connect($server, $username, $password);
mysql_select_db($database);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM users WHERE username = 'bob'") or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row["email"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See also: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php
There are a few good examples